# Inconsistent column size 2 1 train.data while using CRF tool

Tags: csv, crf++

When I run command

```
crf_learn -c 4.0 template train.data model
```

in cmd prompt it shows an error:

```
inconsistent column size 2  1 train.data while using CRF tool
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says you have "inconsistent column size" in your input train file. That is one or more of your rows have different number of columnts.

Check whether number of columns is same in all the lines of your input train file.

ex:

a b c d

a b c